# Using Laravel JSON response inside a __toString method

Tags: laravel, symfony

I have method in my class that returns a JSON response.

```
public function response(){

    return \Response::json(['data'=>'somedata']);
}
```

To be able to use more chain methods I want to use the __toString() method whenever I want to return an object as a response. Like this:

```
public function __toString(){

    return $this->response();

}
```

But I get this error:

```
Method MyClass::__toString() must return a string value
```

Which makes sense but how can I do that. I looked in Laravel and Symfony `JsonResponse` classes and couldn't find a method to fix this. I tried the `getContent()` but that is just a string not a proper Json response.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found a solution. I don't know if it is the best but here it is:

```
public function __toString(){

    $this->response()->send();
    return '';
}
```

Which is actually a call to `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::send()` method instead of returning an string.

Answer (score 0):

Thyis is a late response but I found a better solution, letting Laravel handle the response:

```
public function __toString(){
    return Response::json($this)->content() ' Returns a string
}
```